# sed find and replace with curly braces

Tags: sed

I am trying to use this command:

```
sed -i 's#\{test1\}#test2#' /example/myfile.txt
```

To replace instances of `{test1}` with `test2`.

I get the error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 17: Invalid preceding regular expression
```

Am I not escaping the curly braces correctly?

Comment: Hmm.. I removed the back slashes and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
sed -i 's#{test1}#test2#' /example/myfile.txt
```

You don't need escape `{}`

Answer (score 28):

You aren't escaping the curly braces at all. In `sed`, the default regular expressions are BREs, where `\{` and `\}` indicate a range expression. Since `test1` isn't a range, your BRE is incorrect.

To fix it, you can either drop the backslashes (braces aren't special in BREs) or keep it the same and tell sed to use EREs (`-r` flag with GNU sed, `-E` flag with BSD/MacOSX sed).

Comment: TIL BRE ERE. BREs are pretty handy in the `sed` world.

Comment: TIL: BRE: Basic Regular Expression, ERE: Extended Regular Expression; TIL: Today I Learned :)