# sed windows - find and replace with curly braces

Tags: regex, windows, sed

I would like to replace any

```
...
title = {{ some text }}
...
```

to

```
...
title = { some text }
...
```

Indeed, I want to replace double curly braces to one (in windows 7).

I came up sing sed but apparently sed in windows does not work properly.
Here is a simple test that shows the problem.
I want to replace double curly braces {{ with one { .
Here what I am trying to do:

```
sed "s/{{/{/g" file.txt
```

However I get this error

```
sed: 1: "s/": unterminated substitute pattern
```

I have seen this but apparently it doesn't work in Windows os:
[sed find and replace with curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205669/sed-find-and-replace-with-curly-braces)

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: What sed version do you use, is it in `CYGWIN` or `sed for Windows`. I have no problem to run your command `sed "s/{{/{/g" file.txt` in cygwin.

Comment: @BMW I was using `sed for Windows` and it seems it doesn't work with `{`. After your comment I installed `CYGWIN` and it works fine.
Maybe you want make your comment as an answer then I can accept it.

Comment: sure, updated with answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What sed version do you use, is it `sed in CYGWIN` or `sed for Windows`. I have no problem to run your command `sed "s/{{/{/g" file.txt` in cygwin.

If you run the sed from a windows version `sed for windows`, seems it doesn't work with `{`. Try in CYGWIN.

Comment: Also an alternative answer would be the one which is given by @NeronLeVelu in a comment to his answer (i.e. using -e option for `sed for Windows`)

Answer (score 2):

Try escaping them:

```
sed "s/\{\{/{/g" file.txt
```

Comment: I've tried it as well. this is the error I get: 

    sed: 1: "s//": unterminated substitute in regular expression

Comment: doesn't work. the error I get : sed: 1: "'s//": invalid command code '

Answer (score 0):

with ?

```
sed "s/\(\([{}]\)\2\)/\2/g"
```

to avoid multiple { and } in pattern and associate interpretation. (work for { and } at once)

Comment: still it doesn't work with `sed for Windows` but it works fine with `CYGWIN`.

Comment: --posix option is available on windows (not sur, documentation of GNU sed i found does not specify this ) ? also try -e bedore the string of command

Comment: thanks for your comment. Using -e indeed solves the problem in `sed for Windows`. However, I opted for CYGWIN which seems considering my problem is more consistent with the Linux version of sed command.