# How to use sed to find lines with a specific string and output to new file

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I am learning sed, so please bear with me. I am trying to use sed to find all files containing "install" in a log and output to a new file. Here's an example of the file being searched:

```
2016-05-04 07:38:46 install libcairomm
2016-05-05 07:38:47 status half-installed libcairomm
2016-05-05 07:39:49 status unpacked libcairomm
```

So, it would output the first line only. Here is what I have been trying with some other variations as well:

```
sed -n '/[0-9]{2} install/p' > new.txt
```

All the variations of this I have tried have not done anything. It creates an empty file.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed find and replace with curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205669/sed-find-and-replace-with-curly-braces)

Comment: Maybe awk would make more sense? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077631/is-it-possible-to-print-different-lines-to-different-output-files-using-awk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Using sed

Observe that the following returns nothing:

```
$ sed -n '/[0-9]{2} install/p' file
```

But, this works:

```
$ sed -n '/[0-9]\{2\} install/p' file
2016-05-04 07:38:46 install libcairomm
```

The issue is that, in sed's default basic regular expressions, `{` and `}` are treated as ordinary characters.  To make them special, they must be escaped with a backslash.

Alternatively, one can specify `-E` so that `sed` uses the more modern Extended Regular Expressions:

```
$ sed -En '/[0-9]{2} install/p' file
2016-05-04 07:38:46 install libcairomm
```

#### Saving to file

To save the output in a file, instead of displaying it in the terminal, add back the redirection `> new.txt`:

```
sed -n '/[0-9]\{2\} install/p' file > new.txt
```

Or:

```
sed -En '/[0-9]{2} install/p' file > new.txt
```

#### Compatibility

On very old versions of GNU sed, one cannot use `-E`.  One must use `-r` instead:

```
sed -rn '/[0-9]{2} install/p' file > new.txt
```

## Using grep

This task does not require sed's many advanced features.  `grep` is sufficient:

```
$ grep -E '[0-9]{2} install' file
2016-05-04 07:38:46 install libcairomm
```

Or:

```
grep -E '[0-9]{2} install' file >new.txt
```

Comment: Oh, I see, I forgot the input as well. Thank you! That was a helpful explanation

Comment: @rrfeva Glad that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Your command, `sed -n '/[0-9]{2} install/p' > new.txt` is using Basic RegEx or BRE. [The GNU Sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/BRE-vs-ERE.html#BRE-vs-ERE) manual explains the difference between BRE and Extended RE or ERE.

To solve your issue, use ERE with the `-E` or `-r` flags:

```
sed -rn '/[0-9]{2} install/p' > new.txt
```

Or, use backslashes to escape the curly braces in BRE:

```
sed -n '/[0-9]\{2\} install/p' > new.txt
```