# How to replace a hashtag curly bracket string with an environment variable by using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have being trying to write a bash script that can search recursively in a directory and replace multiple strings e.g. `#{DEMO_STRING_1}` etc with an environment variable e.g. `$sample1`.

Full script:

```
#!/bin/sh

find /my/path/here -type f -name '*.js' -exec sed -i \
    -e 's/#{DEMO_STRING_1}/'"$sample1"'/g' \
    -e 's/#{DEMO_STRING_2}/'"$sample2"'/g' \
    -e 's/#{DEMO_STRING_3}/'"$sample3"'/g' \
    -e 's/#{DEMO_STRING_4}/'"$sample4"'/g' \
    -e 's/#{DEMO_STRING_5}/'"$sample5"'/g' \
    -e 's/#{DEMO_STRING_6}/'"$sample6"'/g' \
    -e 's/#{DEMO_STRING_7}/'"$sample7"'/g' \
    -e 's/#{DEMO_STRING_8}/'"$sample8"'/g' \
    {} +
```

I can not figure out how to replace strings with hashtag with curly brackets.

I tried this example: [sed find and replace with curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205669/sed-find-and-replace-with-curly-braces) or [Environment variable substitution in sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584894/environment-variable-substitution-in-sed) but I can not figure out how to combine them.

What I am missing? I searched also for characters that need to be escaped e.g. [What characters do I need to escape when using sed in a sh script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32907/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-when-using-sed-in-a-sh-script) but again not the characters that I need.

The specific format is throwing the following error:

`sed: bad option in substitution expression`

Where am I going so wrong?

**Update:** Sample of environment variables:

1. https://www.example.com
2. /sample string/
3. 12345-abcd-54321-efgh
4. base64 string

All the cases above are environment variables that I would like to replace. All environment variables are within double quotes.

Comment: Escape `{` and `}` but it also depends on the content of `"$sample1"`

Comment: The error message suggests that one or more of the environment variable values contains a slash character.  You could address that by choosing a different delimiter for the `s` commands, but for that to be reliable, there has to be *some* convention for which characters may appear in those values.

Comment: please update the question with examples of what's in the `$sampleX` variables, especially any that may contain characters other than numbers and letters

Comment: @markp-fuso I have updated the question with samples of environment variables.

Comment: There are better templating engines available than trying to roll your own.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That makes a lot of sense as many of my environment variables include slash characters. What other command I could use that could process all these cases that I added?

Comment: @chepner such as Jinja2 you mean? I am trying to use sed common linux tool. Any other suggestion?

Comment: `sed's` default delimiter is `/`; you can change this to another character but you'll need to pick a character that does not show up in any of the `$sampleX` values (eg, `@`, `|`, `+`); an alternative is to go through the `$sampleX` values and escape all instances of the same character you're using as a `sed` delimiter

Comment: @markp-fuso I could do that but these values are autogenerates are not fixed values. I was thinking of a generic solution. Maybe I would use Jinja2 instead of sed.

Comment: there are other 'tools' that can do the job ... `awk`, `perl`, etc ... but all will have the same issue of having to distinguish between characters used as delimiters vs characters that show up in the data; doable but will require some careful design ...

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to understand that the environment variable references are expanded by the shell, as it prepares to execute the command, not by the command itself (`sed` in this case).  The command sees only the results of the expansions.

In your case, that means that if any of the environment variables' values contain characters that are meaningful to `sed` in context, such as unescaped (to `sed`) slashes (`/`), then `sed` will attribute special significance to them instead of interpreting them as ordinary characters.  For example, given a `sed` command such as

```
sed -e "s/X/${var}/" <<EOF
Replacement:  X
EOF
```

, if the value of `$var` is `Y` then the output will be

```
Replacement: Y
```

, but if the value of `$var` is `/path/to/Y` then `sed` will fail with the same error you report.  This happens because the `sed` command actually run is the same as if you had typed

```
sed -e s/X//path/to/Y
```

, which contains an invalid `s` instruction.  Probably the best alternative would be to escape the replacement-string characters that otherwise would be significant to `sed`.  You can do that by interposing a shell function:

```
escape_replacement() {
  # replace all \ characters in the first argument with double backslashes.
  # Note that in order to do that here, we need to escape them from the shell
  local temp=${1//\\/\\\\}

  # Replace all & characters with \&
  temp=${temp//&/\\&}

  # Replace all / characters with \/, and write the result to standard out.
  # Use printf instead of echo to avoid edge cases in which the value to print
  # is interpreted to be or start with an option.
  printf -- "%s" "${temp//\//\\/}"
}
```

Then the script would use it like this:

```
find /my/path/here -type f -name '*.js' -exec sed -i \
    -e 's/#{DEMO_STRING_1}/'"$(escape_replacement "$sample1")"'/g' \
...
```

Note that you probably also want to use a shebang line that explicitly specifies a shell that supports substitution references (`${parameter/pattern/replacement}`), because these are not required by POSIX, and you might run into a system where `/bin/sh` is a shell that does not support them. If you're willing to rely on Bash then that should be reflected in your shebang line.  Alternatively, you could prepare a version of the `escape_replacement` function that does not rely on substitution references.

Comment: It works, it makes sense what you say. I did not think about it before but the function that you wrote escape the character and it works. Regarding the shebang I am using a container (Alpine) that has only `/bin/sh` but I installed `bash` and it works. Great input much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `perl` - you don't need to escape anything.

With your shell variable **exported** you can access it via `$ENV{name}` inside perl.

examples:

```
samples=(
    https://www.example.com
    '/sample string/'
    12345-abcd-54321-efgh
    'base64 string'
    $'multi\nline'
)

for sample in "${samples[@]}"
do
    echo '---'
    export sample
    echo 'A B #{DEMO_STRING_1} C' |
        perl -pe 's/#{DEMO_STRING_1}/$ENV{sample}/g'
done
echo '---'
```

Output:

```
---
A B https://www.example.com C
---
A B /sample string/ C
---
A B 12345-abcd-54321-efgh C
---
A B base64 string C
---
A B multi
line C
---
```

To add the `-i` option you can: `perl -pi -e 's///'`

Comment: Yeah I could use this but unfortunately I use a container and I am trying to keep it as small as possible. Installing `Perl` it could as an option I will try it.